# Meteor Cluster: with options: undefined

Tags: meteor, microservices, meteor-blaze

After Meteor cluster simple setup, I am presently getting this on the log

```
I20180719-11:04:44.210(1)? Cluster: connecting to 'mongodb' discovery backend
I20180719-11:04:44.297(1)? Cluster: with options:  undefined
```

I am of the opinion that more configuration is needed than what I have done here [Using Meteor Cluster for microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419149/using-meteor-cluster-for-microservice) but I seem not to find any documentation pointing to it.

How can I get the full setup?

Comment: Can you spot in the GitHub repository a line that contains a string named "with options"? Should be a good starting point to backtrack what object is required at this place

Comment: Thanks, @Jankapunkt. I think the package is obsolete, and Kadira is no longer with Meteor to maintain it. I read on the Meteor doc that ```DPP.connection``` suffices for this. Any tutorial to kickstart with ```DPP.connection```? Or just the snippet to get started.

Comment: The docs definitely have it documented plus there is a package named ddp-login for login users to a remote meteor app via ddp so they can call remote methods and subscribe to publications

Comment: @kehinde, did you got the solution for this. As I am also having the same logs. What to do help me out.
Thanks

Comment: @Parveenyadav though I did not, finally resolved to use Meteor DDP client. It worked briliantly.  https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html what I was trying to achieve was establish communication between multiple meteor apps. Jankapunkt suggested it.

Comment: @kehinde, I am using cluster only to because my Meteor app crashed automatically after a few hours without logs any error or exception.
I am unable to find out the reason why my app service kill automatically.